# How to extend/subclass SearchLogic::Search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

Here is what I'm trying:

### app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def searchlogic(conditions = {})
      ProductSearch.new(self, scope(:find), conditions)
    end
  end
end
```

### app/models/product_search.rb

```
require "searchlogic/search"

class ProductSearch < SearchLogic::Search

  include SearchLogic

  def foobar
    puts :hello_world
  end

end
```

### test

```
~/project $ script/console
>> @search = Product.searchlogic
```

> NameError: uninitialized constant SearchLogic

What's the appropriate way to subclass or extend `SearchLogic::Search`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering there's not very much searchlogic help here on SO, I decided not to delete this question and instead answer it myself.

The Module name is `Searchlogic` with a lowercase `L`.

Here is the correct `app/models/product_search.rb`

```
class ProductSearch < Searchlogic::Search

  include Searchlogic

  def foobar
    puts :custom_method
  end

end
```